# How to get data from more than 2 tables in SQL Server with joins

Tags: sql-server

I want to get data based on user login. If `user1` is logged in, `user1` data only should be populated instead of all others data.

I created a table like this, I have 3 tables pond, users, CustomerDevices. I want to show data with giving only one value in query like 'user1'. But I'm getting duplicate records. Based on username I want to pick the customerid and based on customerid need to get the imei and need all the imei data in the table.

```
SELECT temp, p.imei, timestatmp
FROM dbo.pond AS p
INNER JOIN customerdevices AS cd ON p.imei = cd.imei 
INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.username = 'user1'
```

Sample data:

```
 id deviceid    timestatmp       ph       do    temp          imei
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 97 1001    2020-02-06 18:38:31.610 4.32    8.30    26.00   869668021731
181 1001    2020-02-07 18:19:07.967 8.10    6.93    24.00   869668021731
182 1001    2020-02-07 18:24:08.253 8.09    6.73    24.00   869668021731
183 1001    2020-02-07 18:29:10.520 8.10    6.72    24.00   869668021731
```

`id` is the primary key of this table.

Table `Users`:

```
Id  Username    Password    CustomerId
---------------------------------------
4   user1        user1@123  Cust1001
```

`id` is the primary key of this table.

Table `CustomerDevices`:

```
CustomerId  imei
-------------------------
Cust1001    869668021731
```

Here, `imei` is the primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not joining your users table to anything. Try this...

```
SELECT temp,p.imei,timestatmp
FROM dbo.pond as p
inner JOIN customerdevices as cd ON p.imei = cd.imei 
inner Join users as u on cd.CustomerId = u.CustomerId
where u.username='user1'
```